# Using ActiveAndroid and MultiDexApplication

Tags: java, android, activeandroid, android-multidex

I'm having trouble initializing ActiveAndroid in my project. It is state that the application tag in the manifest needs to be like so:

```
<application android:name="com.activeandroid.app.Application" ...>
```

Unfortunately, I have it already as this

```
<application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

It says you can fix the problem by having the class that is in the application tag be a sub-class of ActiveAndroid.

> Notice also that the application name points to the ActiveAndroid application class. **This step is required for ActiveAndroid to work.** If you already point to a custom Application class, just make that class a subclass of com.activeandroid.app.Application.
>
> If you are using a custom Application class, just extend com.activeandroid.app.Application instead of android.app.Application
>
> public class MyApplication extends com.activeandroid.app.Application { ...

Is there a way for me to remedy this problem? I can't change the code to the MultiDexApplication class because it is part of the Android SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MultiDexApplication is Application subclass ([MultiDexApplication](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html)), so extends and configure ActiveAndroid.

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Configuration config = new Configuration.Builder(this)
    .setDatabaseName("mydb.db")
    .setDatabaseVersion(1)
    .create();
    ActiveAndroid.initialize(config);
    }
}
```

In your manifest,

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication">
```

Comment: That should be `new Configuration.Builder(this)` not `new Configuration(this)`.

Comment: Ah. Good catch. Fixed.